# How to manage two divs with absolute position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to solve task, where is problem with div width. The problem is that I need to have set position to absolute for both divs (See picture - div1 and div2).

[image: image of divs]

Div1 has property

> min-width:280px

And the other div should have width of the rest page.

Problem is how to handle this min-width argument if the width of first div will be more than `280px`.

Is there any solution, how to set div2 dynamically too without using JS?
Positions of both divs can not be changed, it must stay set on absolute.

Comment: the answer is: use javascript.

Comment: why does it need to be absolute? is it because your assignment question asked this or are you trying to achieve something that you think only absolute positioning will achieve it?

Comment: Why a `min-width` and not just `width`?  Under what conditions will this div grow beyond 280?

Comment: share your code of create a fiddle for more information about your code.

Comment: You _could_ use a `table`. If you're not scared of them.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gbQXy/ here is example. Huangism> I am asked to do it like this. The problem in code is that i must somehow define the width of the second div to fill page.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at www.yaml.de and then look at columns layout it may give you some idea.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure about the reason why the divs have to be absolutely positioned, but I can admit that you can set them in absolute container and position as table cells:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">Some dynamic content here</div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    display: table-row;
    /*Set your top-right-bottom-left absolute position here*/
}

.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.left {
    min-width: 280px;
}

.right {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check the fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/3QGfj/

Otherwise I afraid you should use Javascript.

Comment: I change your HTML code to: `<div class="container">
    <div class="left">The width is supposed to be or can be under some</div>
    <div class="right">dfsfdsfddasdsadasdasdasdddasdsadsadsadadsf</div>
</div>` and the line is not wrapped correctly.

Comment: @user1554427, sorry, how do you expect it to be wrapped? Considering that it doesn't contain whitespaces and both contents don't fit.

Comment: You can set `overflow: hidden;` on the `.container` class. It will cut the right div. Is it ok for you?

Comment: The cut is not good, my specification does not allow it. Maybe I must use JS yet. :/ I appreciate your and others advices.

Comment: You are welcome. Anyway, it's only a basic idea, you could develop it according to your specification requirements.